# Why does my delegate aiming to get data to update one form from another form comes up blank? c#

Tags: c#, forms, delegates

Apologies for the explaining, This is my first time coding C#.

So my goal is to display  the inputs in a  label  in the Forms Load  event. Here is my code so far

```
public  DelegateText DelFirstName; 

public FrmConfirm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DelFirstName = new DelegateText(sic.GetFirstName);
}

private void FrmConfirm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblFirstName.Text = DelFirstName(sic.FirstName);
}
```

When I run it, it only shows a blank label. There are no syntax errors showing. I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

Well you are assigning an object as a string. You should probably do lblFirstName.Text = sic.FirstName; (given that sic.FirstName is a non-empty string).

Comment: I tried that as well but it yielded the same results.